# Can hypnosis increase breast size?

Tags: psychology, hypnotism, breast, breast-enlargement

[Dr Mark Griffiths Blog](http://drmarkgriffiths.wordpress.com/2012/10/03/bust-a-move-can-hypnosis-increase-breast-size/)

> Also in 1977, Dr. Richard Willard published a study in the American
>   Journal of Clinical Hypnosis. Using a slightly different technique to
>   the previously published studies with a sample of 22 women (aged 19 to
>   54 years), Willard reported an average increase in breast size of
>   nearly one and a half inches following a 12-week program. In this
>   study, the women practiced self-hypnosis and visual imagery (rather
>   than being hypnotized by a practitioner). Those who could best
>   visualize their breasts getting bigger were the ones who showed the
>   greatest increases in breast size. Other main findings reported were:
>
> - 85% reported a significant breast enlargement before they had been measured
> - 46% had to buy larger bras after the study
> - The average increase in breast circumference was 1.37 inches
> - The average increase in the vertical breast measurement was 0.67 inches
> - The average increase in horizontal breast measurement was 1.01 inches
> - Only two women who (subjectively) felt there was no significant increase, did (objectively) have a measurable increase in breast size

Is there any truth to this?

Comment: And does it work for men? :)

Comment: I found the paper that the quote [referred too](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029157.1977.10403875#.UbnAgfnImSc), and it was published in American Journal of Clinical Hypnosis. I checked which papers cited it, and they all came from either that journal or what looked like pseudo-scientific books. It doesn't prove anything though.

Comment: I'm curious how they determined which test subjects were better at "visualizing" a mammary volume increase. Also, no control group, so no useful study. Shame.

Comment: @TimPietzcker "Three of the women received a hypnotic suggestion about breast size increase (i.e., to visualize larger breasts) whereas the other three were the control group and received no hypnotic suggestion." From the blog. They actually used a control group.

Comment: @Wertilq: Ah, OK. I'd still argue that a) three persons are not enough for a control group, b) hypnosis vs. non-hypnosis is not a viable control strategy. You'd need to do at least "real hypnosis" vs. "placebo hypnosis".

Comment: How do you do placebo hypnosis? It's self hypnosis that is taught to them, and they imagine their breasts growing, how do you do placebo version of that?

Comment: @Wertilq Let them imagine the breasts growing bigger from someone else? :p

Comment: @Benjol - I'm sure there's a study if looking at one's junk mail for 2 hours would work for men.